# CountIF error with <0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I would need some help again with another excel countif expression. I have the line i2:al2 which contains leftover stock data.I am building a worksheet to calculate remaining stocks in % as per supervisor's wish.

As I am working with %, for example if I say that 90% sales that means we have 103 stock left and with 91% sales I have 100 stock left.

Anyways I got around to count the number of stock left in line i2:a12 using countifs.

Example if I need to calculate leftover stock for sales at 90% which means leftover stock level of 100 to 102. I have used :

```
=countif(range,">100")-countif(range,">102")
```

This method seems to work till I reach negative numbers, i.e. oversales. For example, if I try to do the following:

```
 =countif(range,"-100")-countif(range,">0")
```

the formula seems to stop working. If I count manually using a conditional formatting I get a totally different answer for the oversales.

Maybe I am getting the logic of the countif function wrong. My purpose for the expressison is:

```
=count(in range, values >=X & <=Y)
```

As I have only access to excel 2003 I cannot use Countifs method. Anyone could help me on this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: try `SUMPRODUCT((range>=X)*(range<=Y))`

Comment: Try using "=-100" instead of just "-100".

Comment: @simoco 's solution should work, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula:

```
=SUM((range>=x)*(range<=y))
```

For that to work, you need to press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER for that to use array formula.

Alternatively, using what simoco gives in the comment works too without having to save as array formula.